# Compiler confusing assignment and comparison

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, operators

I have an object that is an entity in LINQ `CP_Stop`, and I'm trying to fill the properties with different data.

```
Dim stop As New CP_Stop
With stop 
    .fdStart = dtpStart.Value
    .fdEnd = dtpEnd.Value
    .CP_Cause = cause
    .User = user
    .Machine = machine
    .CP_Production = _presenter.GetProduction()
End With
```

The first two assignments are been made, as well as the third one, `CP_Cause` is an object that I query earlier in the method, but when it comes to the fourth one, it crashes.
The error is as follows:

> Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Entities.Users' and 'Entities.Users'.

The interesting part is that if a switch for example the Cause and user assignation, the first one is made and the other one crashes. The same scenario with all the other object assignations. It seems to me that the compiler is confusing the assignment.

I've tried several ways to make the assignment, like making it on another method but it always crashes after the first one.

Comment: You call it "crashing" and you say it's a runtime error, but that error is a little unusual at runtime. Are you sure it's not a compile-time error?

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On`?

Comment: I have both options on, and you're correct minitech i meant that when i'm debugging it shows me the error on VS

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework here, or LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure you can have a column property which contains a reference to another row of another table, since how would it translate in sql ? You have to use a key for that (expl : userId instead of user).
You might wanna look at EntityRef and EntitySet, to handle nicelt one to one / one to many relationship, but this is complex stuff.

Comment: If this Entity Framework, and the relationship between the two tables is defined in the model, then the OP's example is perfectly legal.

Comment: Yes it was legal, the error I posted was what the debugger said, on a try catch block the exception was diferent context objects.
Thank you all